# Mi proyecto de docker es muy lento

Tags: docker, symfony

Buen día comunidad, tengo docker en windows 10 y donde cargo un contenedor que ejecuta symfony, cuando entro al navegador a carga el proyecto es muy lento, tarda entre 2 a 3 minutos en cargar una pagina.

Ya configure los recursos a usar pero no mejoro la velocidad de respuesta.

Alguien sabe que sera?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Luego presiona en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/516748/edit) y agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

*Docker para Windows* y *Docker para Mac* presentan un problema de rendimiento para la sincronización de archivos.  Cuando desarrollamos toda la cache es volátil.

**¿Que quiere decir?**

Que siempre se regenera.

**¿y eso que?**

Bueno, dado que **symfony** tiene que escribir en el sistema de ficheros, el proceso toma un tiempo con este problema.

Tambien no te dejes llevar por esta respuesta, existen otros factores que no tiene que ver con *docker* y *symfony*. Te recomiendo usar *discos de estado solido* o las nuevas *NVEM* para el sistema de ficheros o WSL2.